# C# Ajuda para carregar resources PNG de DLL externo

Tags: c#

Criei o `Dll` de resources com I*magens PNG* em C# quando compilo para fazer a leitura no `PictureBox` do *Visual Studio* recebo a noticia de `NUll` ou de `missing System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

[image]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory +@"\PNGRES.dll");
Stream strm = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("resources.PNG"+(string)asm.GetManifestResourceNames()[102]);
Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(strm);
pictureBox1.Image = b;
```

Comment: Amigo você tem que dar mais detalhes sobre sua dúvida/pergunta. Qual erro está dando? oque você está querendo fazer? vai carregar essa imagem onde? de onde??? Está fazendo isso onde?? DÊ DETALHES.

Comment: Olá, Carlos, e bem-vindo! Acredito que seu conteúdo seja na verdade um exemplo de solução ao invés de uma pergunta, correto? Você pode postar uma pergunta (o que irá ajudar desenvolvedores no futuro a achar este post) e respondê-la você mesmo.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para que a comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante que se explique detalhadamente o seu problema.

Sugiro que leia os artigos: [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como realizar uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

O código é um pouco diferente do seu, mas, essa forma deveria ser revista, é muito simples quando adicionamos a referencia no projeto, mas, fiz um exemplo carregando dinamicamente a `dll`.

A ***biblioteca*** chama-se: `Biblioteca.dll`, o ***resource*** (arquivo `.resx`) chama-se: `Imagens.resx`, logo o nome para o colocar no *construtor* da *classe* `ResourceManager` é `Biblioteca.Imagens`, como está no código. Dentro desse resource tem 3 imagens com os respectivos nomes: **_1**, **_2** e **_3** que no caso é valor do `GetObject`.

Tendo esse valor (`Object`), faça um `cast` `(Imagem)` e passe o valor para `PictureBox1.Image` que será carregado a imagem ...

```
string path = @"C:\Projetos\";
string real = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, @"Biblioteca.dll");

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(real);
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Biblioteca.Imagens", assembly);
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)resourceManager.GetObject("_3");
```

[Referencia principal do código](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(v=vs.71).aspx)